# How to directly draw on form buffer (using pointers)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some buffer of visual data, which is being changed pretty quickly. And i need to draw it to form, with at least 60fps.

In all other similar questions i found - it was advised to use `Bitmap` as temporary buffer, like this:

```
        public unsafe TimeSpan CopyToFormBuffer(float* buff)
        {
            var b = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
            var bd = b.LockBits(this.ClientRectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            //this is more of a GPU work, but for simplicity i put it on CPU:
            var hy = bd.Scan0;
            for (int y = 0; y < this.ClientSize.Height; ++y, hy += bd.Stride)
            {
                var hx = hy;
                for (int x = 0; x < this.ClientSize.Width; ++x, hx += 4, buff += 4)
                {
                    var p = (byte*)hx;
                    p[3] = Convert.ToByte(buff[0] * 255);
                    p[2] = Convert.ToByte(buff[1] * 255);
                    p[1] = Convert.ToByte(buff[2] * 255);
                    p[0] = Convert.ToByte(buff[3] * 255);
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bd);
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
            sw.Stop();
            return sw.Elapsed;
        }
```

```
        private unsafe void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var buff = (float*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(this.ClientSize.Width * this.ClientSize.Height * 4 * sizeof(float));

            for (var i = 100; i > 0; i--)
                MessageBox.Show(CopyToFormBuffer(buff).ToString());

        }
```

But this way, line:

```
            this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
```

makes additional copy operation, which is unacceptably slow (80-90ms on my pc in full screen mode).

So, is there a way to draw on form buffer directly, like i do with `Bitmap`'s `Scan0`?

Note, even though in example buffer of visual data is just array of raster 4хFloat colors, i need the same for more complex formats, so some sort of color conversion would need to be done anyway.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is bad.  Is `this` the windows `Form` you are drawing on?  If so, you really need to make use of the form's `Paint` event and its supplied graphics member.

Comment: To give us some perspective, could you provide the bitmap size that took 80-90ms to process.

Comment: @TnTinMn 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of what you're trying to accomplish using the Forms Paint() event. This will be much quicker than allocating a screen buffer every frame. You can modify the "buff" pixel buffer anywhere in your form and it will be repainted in the form. You just need to call this.Invalidate() to force the Paint to be called. Any time you change buff, call Invalidate on the Form itself.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private unsafe float* buff;

        public unsafe Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buff = (float*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(this.ClientSize.Width * this.ClientSize.Height * 4 * sizeof(float));
        }

        private unsafe void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var b = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
            var bd = b.LockBits(this.ClientRectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            //this is more of a GPU work, but for simplicity i put it on CPU:
            var hy = bd.Scan0;
            for (int y = 0; y < this.ClientSize.Height; ++y, hy += bd.Stride)
            {
                var hx = hy;
                for (int x = 0; x < this.ClientSize.Width; ++x, hx += 4, buff += 4)
                {
                    var p = (byte*)hx;
                    p[3] = Convert.ToByte(buff[0] * 255);
                    p[2] = Convert.ToByte(buff[1] * 255);
                    p[1] = Convert.ToByte(buff[2] * 255);
                    p[0] = Convert.ToByte(buff[3] * 255);
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bd);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
            sw.Stop();

            Debug.WriteLine($"Frame took {sw.Elapsed}ms to draw");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see, using `CreateGraphics` makes it is slower. But, your way line with `DrawImage` takes 50-55ms to execute. Which is still <20fps and really far from 60fps.

Comment: You're doing pixel level manipulation which is O(N^2). That's not going to be good on the CPU, that kind of stuff needs to be done on the GPU. You'll want to look at DirectX or OpenGL Frameworks.

Comment: for pixel conversion i gonna use OpenCL, but buffer copying shouldn't take 50ms to process. `Buffer.BlockCopy`, for instance, does copy the same amount of byte in 8-9ms, which is acceptable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's actually 2-3ms, i was testing on 4x bigger byte array.

Comment: So you're set then?

Comment: No, that copying from one byte array to another takes 2-3ms. And original question, which would give me address of forms buffer, so i can copy something there - isn't answered.

Comment: You’re trying to do something in Windows Forms that it’s not designed for, high performance graphics. I suggested you use a graphics library such as OpenGL or DirectX which will easily run 60fps. I’m not going to write the code for you though, you’ll need to read the documentation and go from there.

Comment: I do know OpenGL and basics of DirectX. But all calculations are already gonna be on GPU, and they are gonna be different from what OpenGL and DirectX does. I need only a way to copy stuff to some sort of screen buffer. Doing it through textures in 2D drawing mode of OpenGL is a hotfix, there should be more proper way. And no, OpenGL handles all the screen buffers stuff itself and doesn't provide access to it. And as far as i'm aware - DirectX too.